# printing out the first 888 happy numbers

Tags: c++, increment, iostream

So i have this function that checks whether a number is a happy number or not. It returns either true or false.

```
bool is_happy(int x) //Let the function determine if the number is happy
{

int result;
while (x != 1) //If x == 1, it is a happy number
{
    result = 0;
    while (x) //Until every digit has been summed
    {
        result += (x % 10) * (x % 10); //Square digit and add it to total
        x /= 10;
    }
    x = result;
    if (x == 4) //if x is 4, its a sad number
        return false;
}
return true;
}
```

it is working as intended and returns true when X is a happy number.

What i am trying to do is print the first 888 happy numbers.

I tried setting up a while loop that has an integer b that increments

```
int b=0;
while(b<=888) {
b++;
}
```

however, i am not sure how to include and increment X, whenever i try and include and increment x, it simply prints out the first happy number 888 times.

My issue is attempting to increment x, and whenever it reaches a happy number it outputs that happy number, then increments b. I can only use iostream and no other libraries.

EDIT: Apologies for lacking clarity!

I am trying to print out the first 888 happy numbers, i have the function which checks if the number is happy. I am trying to make a loop that prints out the first 888 numbers that make the function return True.

Many thanks!

Comment: Show your attempt **in code**.

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow this logic.

First, create a variable for the counter. Let's say `int counter = 0;`.

Then, do:

```
while ( counter < 888 )
{

  if ( number == /*happy condition*/)
  {
    //do somehting
    counter++;
  }


  else
  {
    // :(
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass b to your function, and to keep a count of happy numbers:

```
  int b = 0;
  int count = 0;
  while( count < 888 ) {
      if (  is_happy( b ) ) {
         // do something
         count++;
      }
      b++;
  }
```

Comment: That's where copy and paste gets you. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to increment both numbers separately:

```
int b = 0;
for (int x = 1; b < 888; x++) {
    if (is_happy(x)) {
        // print
        b++;
    }
}
```